# loop in cmd for batch downloading

Tags: for-loop, cmd

I've problem with loop in cmd for batch downloading. I want to exectute my python script to downloaded (it working), but in loop in cmd.

without loop, there is

```
python script.py -a mandatory_argument https_adress
```

My loop is like below:

```
for %x in (https_address_1, https_adress_2) do (
   echo %x 
   python script.py -a mandatory_argument %x
)
```

Is there any kind of obvious mistake?

Comment: Are you using the `for` loop in a [tag:batch-file]? if so, change `%x` to `%%x`...

Comment: you are mixing two languages instead you have already python available.

Comment: Depending on the https_addresses you might also have to double quote them (poisenous characters like `&`)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your script.py program. But, the FOR loop variables inside a .bat or .cmd file script must have double percent characters. Using QUOTATION MARK and TILDE are defensive tactics.

```
for %%x in (https_address_1, https_adress_2) do (
   echo "%%~x"
   python script.py -a mandatory_argument "%%~x"
)
```